# Toolbar don't hide on scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

I do everything according to the instructions, but the toolbar remains stationary while scrolling through recyclerview in a fragment.
Recyclerview I have is in the fragment itself

Activity:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/yellow"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/frag_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Fragment:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".note.notes.NotesFragment">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/notes"
    android:paddingTop="72dp"
    android:paddingStart="4dp"
    android:paddingEnd="4dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I will be very grateful for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Make some changes to your XML :

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar_home" >

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_home"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Hope it works for you!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I rummaged around and found a problem, but I don’t fully know how to solve it. If you force a large height into NestedScrollView, for example: 1000dp, then the toolbar begins to hide, but if it has a "match parent" height, this does not happen. Something needs to be done to take into account the height of the recylerview inside the fragment. I hope I was able to convey the problem :)